# MediaPlayer, create item on position

Tags: android, listview, position

I am working on a project with ListView and MediaPlayer. I want to have something like list or array of sounds in raw folder and assign them to a position, for example
position1file to position 0 in listview, position2file to position 1 in listview etc etc...so when user click on for example position 3, MediaPlayer create file that is on position 4 and play it.
I created integer

```
int[] songPos = {R.raw.position1,R.raw.position2,R.raw.position3,R.raw.position4};
```

and mp

```
public static MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

and I tried with this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               String selectedItemPos = (String) getItemAtPosition(position);
               int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(selectedItemPos, songPos, UnitPackage);
               MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(CentralActivity.this, resId);  

               mp.start();
           }
           });
```

But I got error:

```
The method getItemAtPosition(int) is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}
```

and

```
The method getIdentifier(String, String, String) in the type Resources is not applicable for the arguments (String, int[], String)
```

I believe those errors are stupid and easy to fix but since I'm still fairly new in development I have no idea how to fix them. So my question is: How can I fix this? Or Is this the right way to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it Like this:

```
int[] songPos = {R.raw.position1,R.raw.position2,R.raw.position3,R.raw.position4};
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   int resId = songPos[position];
                   MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(CentralActivity.this, resId);  

                   mp.start();
               }
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

`getItemAtPosition` returns Object type (See definition [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29)) I think you need to typecast the object to string.

```
String selectedItemPos = (String) getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Context context = getContext(); // or getBaseContext(), or getApplicationContext()
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/song_name", null, context.getPackageName());
```

here song_name is file named in your RAW folder..

declare string[] of your file named.

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/"+str_arr[position], null, context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: MediaPlayer is not the problem, that code just starts the MP, it's not finished yet. I want to see if this works then to set up MP

Comment: Eh I don't mean to be rude, but do you even know what this question is about? I am trying to get all sound files from raw folder and play them on click. If I click on 12th row it should play 12th file in raw folder. I know how to use MediaPlayer and get file path for file and package name.

Comment: what is this question about? His answer looks like exactly what you need. What is wrong with it?

Comment: @kevinrmannix thnx for favour me..:) I don't know why he is saying this answer as wrong... :)

Comment: @kevinrmannix Look at his edits, that'd tell you whats wrong.

Comment: he wants to get dynamically row files.. and this is way to get this ids programettically...

Comment: Actually no, it will probably give him no resource found error because  raw/str_arr doesn't exist. Since he already created integer he already have ids so he can go like this `int resId = songPos[position];`
and then just: `mp=MediaPlayer.create(CentralActivity.this, resId);`

Comment: int resId = songPos[position]; worked. 
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/"+str_arr[position], null, context.getPackageName());
crashed and gave FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    : E/AndroidRuntime(21457): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
error
@SlimC.How can I give you bounty? Can you write the answer? Or should I wait for better answer